# Fire ckeditor embed plugin and pass url and required parameter

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor, embed

I want to fire ckeditor embed plugin (https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/embed) manually on some action. For example URL from user using input button and then pass this URL to embed plugin so that it can embed that in my ckeditor instance.

I get some Help from this link [CKEditor: call a plugin function without toolbar button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585428/ckeditor-call-a-plugin-function-without-toolbar-button) and use CKEDITOR.instances['editable'].execCommand('YOUR_PLUGIN_NAME_HERE'); This will open embed dialog but i need to fire this plugin. so the user input url will be embeded in my ckeditor.

I also use editor.fire('YOUR_PLUGIN_NAME_HERE',data) method but dont know what to passes in data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just inserting proper widget HTML into CKEditor? When you insert HTML, the [checkWidgets](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_plugins_widget_repository.html#method-checkWidgets) method which reinitializes widgets [gets fired automatically](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/major/plugins/widget/plugin.js#L3018-L3031). If for some reason it doesn't work for you, you can fire that method manually.

Sample code for your input (depending which plugin you use) might look like:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
editor.focus();

// Embed Semantic
// editor.insertHtml('<oembed>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ue6KrclRvY8</oembed>');

// Embed
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertHtml('<div data-oembed-url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lMNRQix_QzQ"><div style="height:0; left:0; padding-bottom:56.2493%; position:relative; width:100%"><iframe allowfullscreen="" scrolling="no" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lMNRQix_QzQ?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" style="border: 0; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;" tabindex="-1"></iframe></div>');

// This code should only be fired in cases where inserting HTML doesn't work fire
// checkWidgets method however it should not really happen
/*setTimeout( function(){
    editor.widgets.checkWidgets();
} ,0 );*/
```

Comment: I also don't know why it is not firing automatically. Thanks for the help ,problem is solved by your solution

Comment: So `insertHtml()` doesn't fire the `checkWidgets()` and you need to run it manually? Could you tell me out of pure curiosity which editor version you use (you can find it at the top of ckeditor/CHANGES.md file)?  I have done my tests in latest CKEditor 4.10.1 full package.

Comment: i think , i am doing it wrong , i was just inserting it by jquery i-e `$('#id').after(data);` also i don't make proper formating like <div data-oembed-url=....,   I don't know much about ckeditor. The above code you provided is working perfectly. In CHANGES.md i am using 4.10 version